# ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, visual-studio-exp-2013

I'm getting the following error using visual Studio Express 2013 for Web. It previously work on 32 bit. My laptop is 64 bit Windows.

ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

I've rebuild the solution with 64 bit cpu selected and no joy.

Comment: Just after typing this I found the solution. If you go into Tools->Options>Web Projects and ensure your have "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects." this resolves the problem.

Comment: 63 Bit? Interesting architecture ;)

Comment: Thanks, corrected my typo, indeed would be an interesting architecture.

Comment: No worries^^ Since you came up with a solution, maybe consider posting the solution as an answer and accept it. That way people with the same problem can spot the answer easier.

Answer (score 61):

If you go into Tools->Options>Web Projects and ensure your have "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects." this resolves the problem.

Comment: In VS 2015 it was Tools -> **Projects and Solutions** -> Web Projects :)

Comment: @JohanHelsén It's Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Web Projects

Comment: I have the same problem with SAP's sapnco.dll, and this managed to solve my problem. BIG THANKS!

Comment: @MoruJackall Yes, exactly!
Sweet Lord. I have been banging my head against the wall for an hour trying to figure out why the SAP sapnco.dll file wouldn't load. I would upvote this answer, and thread, a million times if I could. Thank you!

Comment: this helped my issues regarding 'Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop' Debug Assistant 'BindingFailure' error. Thank you very much.!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me as well. I just need to make sure 3 things in my case. dll which causing this error is of 64 bit. I am running on any CPU platform and last as you mentioned 64 bit version of IIS Express

Comment: This solved my problem, the binary i was including came in 32 and 64 bit flavors.  I was including the 64 bit, had all my project -> build settings correct.   It never occurred to me that the error was coming from IIS Express

Comment: `2023` and this is still very helpful, I realized that I needed the opposite, so by unchecking the option to `Use the 64 bit version of IIS` helped.

Comment: This start happen when i use Visual Studio 2022 to run a old project with .net 4.5.1, in my case, i UNCHECK this option to workl! Thx!

Answer (score 4):

My project/solution was the inverse of the fix here: I needed to un-check the "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects." I'm left assuming that the project is 32 bit, but the only release mode that broke for me was "debug". Viewing it in browser without debug never failed to compile.

I searched numerous questions for the solution, so I thought I would add my fix here. It does seem to work both ways (if it's checked, uncheck it!)

Comment: Hey Tyler welcome to Stack Overflow. This was going through the deletion queue because of your comment "This is probably better as a comment, but I don't have 50 rep yet, so I needed to add it as an answer for visibility." as 'comments as answers' is literally one of the deletion reasons you can vote for. But with some editing this answer can stand on it's own, and it seems to contain valuable information. 
I've voted to keep, but to make sure it survives it needs editing on your part.

Comment: 2 days of searching and googling around and THIS saved my life <3
The DLL I am using only supports x86...

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by trying to run a 64 bit process or dependency on IIS Express of 32 bit.

If you don't want to change for all your projects like suggested in @Shaun Roach's answer you can edit the specific startup project properties and change the Bitness in the Web tab to 64 bit, this will add `<Use64BitIISExpress>false</Use64BitIISExpress>` to your csproj (which by the way is not the same as the default `<Use64BitIISExpress />`).

Comment: *Quick Note*: From my personal experience, sometimes simply adjusting the setting in Options does not apply correctly in Visual Studio and it can be beneficial to add an explicit configuration to your project file if you are still having the issue.

Answer (score 3):

My project is specificly 64bit.

I had to change a Reference to a dll, by adding the 64bit version.
Creating a folder in my project called "x64" and adding the dll, with the property: *Copy to Output Directory : Copy always*

---

I found the solution in an Oracle readme:

Use the following steps for your application to use the 64-bit version of ....dll:

1. Right click on the Visual Studio project.
2. Select Add -> New Folder
3. Name the folder x64.
4. Right click on the newly created x64 folder
5. Select Add -> Existing Item
6. Browse to ...\bin\x64 under your project solution directory.
7. Choose ....64bit.dll
8. Click the 'Add' button
9. Left click the newly added ....dll in the x64 folder
10. In the properties window, set 'Copy To Output Directory' to 'Copy Always'.

For x86 targeted applications, name the folder x86 and add assemblies from the 
...\bin\x86 folder.